# reading 0 in front of numeric

Tags: r, character, numeric

```
vec1 <- c(26, 12, 13, 20, 9)
vac1 <- decode_vec(vec1)
```

The result :

```
vac1 : "11010" "01100" "01101" "10100" "01001"
```

I'm changing vac1 into numeric but 0 keeps disappear.

```
test_1 <- as.numeric(vac1)
```

result

```
11010 1100 1101 10100 1001
```

I tried to recover 0 with sprintf() but it rechanged the vector into character.

```
test_2 <- sprintf("%05d", test_1)

"11010" "01100" "01101" "10100" "01001"
```

I want to make the morse codes into numeric form without losing any 0

Comment: You will not be able to add a leading zero in a numeric vector.

Comment: I agree with previous comment, why would you need to make it numeric ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Numeric vectors will not print with 0 prefixes but we can define our own S3 class that does.  We have defined as.bin.numeric, as.data.frame.bin, format.bin and print.bin methods.  We have not defined a [.bin method so subscripted values will have to be cast back as shown below.  Internally the bin class is stored as ordinary numbers.  Define other methods as needed.

```
library(dst)
library(zoo)

as.bin <- function(x, ...) UseMethod("as.bin")
as.bin.numeric <- function(x, ...) structure(x, class = "bin")

as.data.frame.bin <- zoo:::as.data.frame.yearmon

format.bin <- function(x, ...) {
  x <- unclass(x)
  n <- max(floor(log2(x)) + 1)
  base <- rep(2, n)
  sapply(x, function(y) paste0(encode(base, y), collapse = ""))
}

print.bin <- function(x, ...) print(format(x), ...)
```

Now test these

```
v0 <- c(26, 12, 13, 20, 9)

v <- as.bin(v0)

as.numeric(v)
## [1] 26 12 13 20  9

v
## [1] "11010" "01100" "01101" "10100" "01001"

v + 1
## [1] "11011" "01101" "01110" "10101" "01010"

as.bin(v[1])
## [1] "11010"

data.frame(v = v)
##       v
## 1 11010
## 2 01100
## 3 01101
## 4 10100
## 5 01001
```